# Rhino Mocks: Mocked method returns null

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to mock a data repository object but after setting an expectation on my MockRepository, it returns null every time. My code is as follows:

```
    [Test]
    public void GetById_NotNull()
    {
        Person expectedPerson = new Person() { Id = 1, Name="Jon"};

        MockRepository MockRepository = new MockRepository();
        var FakePersonRepository = MockRepository.StrictMock<IRepository<Person>>();

        FakePersonRepository.Expect(action => action.Get(1)).IgnoreArguments().Return(expectedPerson);

        PersonService PersonService = new PersonService(FakePersonRepository);
        Person returnedPerson = PersonService.Get(1);

        Assert.IsNotNull(returnedPerson);
    }

    //and inside my person service
    public class PersonService
    {
         private IRepository<Person> _PersonRepository;
         public PersonService(IRepository<Person> PersonRepository)
         {
           this._PersonRepository = PersonRepository;
         }

         public Person Get(int Id)
         {
             Person p = _PersonRepository.Get(Id);
             return p;
          }
    }
```

The assertion at the bottom of the Test fails and returned person is always null. I know I must be doing something wrong with my mock....ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris is on the money here. The AAA syntax and using GenerateStub for this senario is best.

```
var FakePersonRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<<IRepository<Person>>();
FakePersonRepository.Stub(x => x.Get(1)).Returns(expectedPerson);

PersonService PersonService = new PersonService(FakePersonRepository);
Person returnedPerson = PersonService.Get(1);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try doing a

```
mockRepository.ReplayAll()
```

after the line where you set your Expect.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, I believe you will need a Replay somewhere with the style of tests you are using; As an alternative, you could use the [newer AAA Syntax](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/16/Rhino-Mocks--Arrange-Act-Assert-Syntax.aspx) along with the static MockRepository.GenerateMock<>()/MockRepository.GenerateStub<>() methods which would not require a Replay.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with RhinoMocks (I've been using Moq), but couldn't:

```
FakePersonRepository.Expect(action => action.Get(1)).IgnoreArguments().Return(expectedPerson);
```

be

```
FakePersonRepository.Expect(action => action.Get(1)).Return(expectedPerson);
```

I also think you need a Replay() with RM.

Comment: Yeah the IgnoreArguments is superfluous. Its the replay I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

With the AAA syntax and GenerateMock you can also verify that PersonRepository is called with the correct parameter and correct number of times:

```
Person expectedPerson = new Person() { Id = 1, Name="Jon"}; 

MockRepository MockRepository = new MockRepository(); 
var FakePersonRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<Person>>(); 

FakePersonRepository.Expect(action => action.Get(1)).Return(expectedPerson).Repeat.Once(); 
PersonService PersonService = new PersonService(FakePersonRepository); 
Person returnedPerson = PersonService.Get(1); 

Assert.IsNotNull(returnedPerson); 
FakePersonRepository.VerifyAllExpectations();
```